# What was Hume's specific view with empiricism?

Tags: hume, empiricism

I've stumbled across empiricism and Hume's view on it. It really interests me, but with the sources I've encountered, I still lack a clear understanding of his view on it.

Comment: this is kinda vague, but potentially helpful for others. what do you know so far?

Comment: Stumbled??!! 

Comment: Bon voyage. *Pax vobis*

Comment: i am all over the place ha @AgentSmith

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the "problem of induction" which David Hume has famously covered in his 1739-40 "A Treatise on Human Nature" and his 1748 "An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding"?

If yes, then his perspective is that induction will result in circular reasoning if in terms of probability and if in terms of demonstration, then every demonstration is not able to be False given acceptance of a demonstration as true.

In a very brief summary of his perspective, humans cannot justify induction or cause & effect through reasoning and that we cannot reliably infer what happens in the future based on prior experiences.

### Further Reading

- https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction

### References

Gutenberg has his works or reprints available for reading for free as they are in the public domain.

- "A Treatise on Human Nature": https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/4705
- "An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding":
  https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/9662/pg9662.txt

Or the internet archive

https://archive.org/details/treatiseofhumann01humeuoft

Answer (score 0):

Empiricism is basically the belief that all knowledge is *a posteriori* to *experience*. We're born as a, his words, *tabula rasa* (blank slate). Experience is what writes on it and that which is written is knowledge, *contra* Descartes, Spinoza, plus Leibniz, who believed in *innate knowledge* i.e. knowledge *a priori* to experience.